# Suppose That $T \in B(X)$ then $\sigma(T) = \sigma(T^{*})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

Suppose $M$ is some complex Banach space.

I proved that if $\lambda \notin \sigma(T^*)$, then $\lambda I - T$ is injective. I am having few issues with surjectivity. We know that

$$\overline{Im(\lambda I - T)} = (Ker (\lambda I - T)^{*})_{\perp} = M$$

Hence, the closure is equal to the whole space. Why does this tells us that

$$Im(\lambda I - T) = M$$

I was thinking somehow proving that $Im(\lambda I  - T)$ is Banach, which will then show that it must be closed. I have no idea how I can do this.

Comment: You're overcomplicating it a bit I think. You should only need that $(\lambda I - T)^* = \lambda I -T^*$ and that an operator $A:X \to X$ is invertible if and only if $A^*: X^* \to X^*$ is invertible. Both of these things aren't very hard to prove.

Comment: This is false. In one dimension it says that every complex number is real. Perhaps a complex conjugate is not visible to me somewhere.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Note that $(\lambda I-T)^* = \lambda I - T^*$ ! The adjoint operator != taking transpose + conjugate complex.

Comment: $(\lambda I -T)^{*}=\mu \lambda -T^{*}$ where $\mu$ is the complex conjugate of $\lambda$.